# Local Storage not storing value. Only storing [object MouseEvent]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css, vue-composition-api

Thanks to @zim, I was able to simplify my code a lot for 2 buttons that store true/false locally. However, for some reason, the button click works, but it is storing [object MouseEvent] as opposed to True / False. I have gone over this multiple times now but can't figure out why it isnt storing the right value.

markup

```
          <div>
              <button type="button" @click="clickPrivateChat">
                  <a key="privateChat" href="#" :class="privateChat?'bg-green-900 hover:bg-green-700':''" class="bg-red-900 text-gray-100 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white group w-full p-3 rounded-md flex flex-col items-center text-xs font-medium">
                      <ChatIcon class="h-6 w-6 text-white"/>
                      <span class="pt-2">Private Chat {{ privateChatOnOrOff }}</span>
                  </a>
              </button>
          </div>

          <div>
              <button type="button" @click="clickAllSounds">
                  <a key="privateChat" href="#" :class="allSounds?'bg-green-900 hover:bg-green-700':''" class="bg-red-900 text-gray-100 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white group w-full p-3 rounded-md flex flex-col items-center text-xs font-medium">
                      <VolumeUpIcon class="h-6 w-6 text-white"/>
                      <span class="pt-2">All Sounds {{ allSoundsOnOrOff }}</span>
                  </a>
              </button>
          </div>
```

Script:

```
  data() {
        return {
           privateChat: (localStorage.getItem("privateChat") === true) ? true : false,
           allSounds: (localStorage.getItem("allSounds") === true) ? true : false,        }
    },
  computed: {
    privateChatOnOrOff() {
        return this.privateChat  ? 'ON' : 'OFF'
    },
    allSoundsOnOrOff() {
        return this.allSounds ? 'ON' : 'OFF'
    }
  },
methods: {
    clickPrivateChat (value) {
      this.privateChat = !this.privateChat
      localStorage.setItem("privateChat", value)
    },
    clickAllSounds (value) {
      this.allSounds = !this.allSounds
      localStorage.setItem("allSounds", value)
    }
setup() {
    const mobileMenuOpen = ref(false)
    const privateChatEnabled = ref(privateChat)
    let privateChatValue = localStorage.getItem("privateChat")
    let privateChat = (privateChatValue === 'true')
    const allSoundsEnabled = ref(allSounds)
    let allSoundsValue = localStorage.getItem("allSounds")
    let allSounds = (allSoundsValue === 'true')
  
    return {
      sidebarNavigation,
      userNavigation,
      mobileMenuOpen,
      tabs,
      userlists,
      team,
      activityItems,
      privateChatEnabled,
      allSoundsEnabled,
    }
  },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Clarification on [@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106546/6277151):*

You're seeing `[object MouseEvent]` in Local Storage because your `click`-handlers are storing the event data (`value` is the `MouseEvent` object from the `click` event) instead of the Boolean changed inside the handler. Since Local Storage only stores strings, it converts the `MouseEvent` object into a string, which is `[object MouseEvent]`, as seen in this demo:

```js
console.log(new MouseEvent({}).toString())
```

The fix is to simply store the intended Boolean:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    clickPrivateChat (value) {
      this.privateChat = !this.privateChat 
      // localStorage.setItem("privateChat", value) ❌ value is a MouseEvent object

      localStorage.setItem("privateChat", this.privateChat) // ✅
    },
    clickAllSounds (value) {
      this.allSounds = !this.allSounds
      // localStorage.setItem("allSounds", value) ❌ value is a MouseEvent object

      localStorage.setItem("allSounds", this.allSounds) // ✅
    }
  }
}
```

When reading from Local Storage, be sure to convert the string back into a Boolean:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // BEFORE:
      // privateChat: (localStorage.getItem("privateChat") === true) ? true : false,
      // allSounds: (localStorage.getItem("allSounds") === true) ? true : false,

      // AFTER:
      privateChat: localStorage.getItem("privateChat") === "true",
      allSounds: localStorage.getItem("allSounds") === "true",
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed you're doing that in `setup()`, but assigning  the result to throwaway variables. To declare the props correctly in `setup()`, replace the `data()` props with `ref`s:

```js
import { ref }  from 'vue'

export default {
  // BEFORE:
  // data() {
  //  return {
  //    privateChat: localStorage.getItem("privateChat") === "true",
  //    allSounds: (localStorage.getItem("allSounds") === "true",
  //  }
  //},

  // AFTER:
  setup() {
    const privateChat = ref(localStorage.getItem("privateChat") === "true")
    const allSounds = ref(localStorage.getItem("allSounds") === "true")

    return {
      privateChat,
      allSounds,
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 1: Options API with Composition API](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-booleans-local-storage-options?file=src/App.vue)

[demo 2: Composition API only](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-booleans-local-storage-composition?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

`value` is an `Event` object, you can't store that in `localStorage`. `localStorage` can only store strings.

You should be storing the value of `this.privateChat` and `this.allSounds`. You need to convert to JSON when storing, and parse it when reading.

```js
data() {
    return {
      privateChat: (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("privateChat") || "false") === true) ? true : false,
      allSounds: (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allSounds"), "false") === true) ? true : false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    privateChatOnOrOff() {
      return this.privateChat ? 'ON' : 'OFF'
    },
    allSoundsOnOrOff() {
      return this.allSounds ? 'ON' : 'OFF'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickPrivateChat(value) {
      this.privateChat = !this.privateChat
      localStorage.setItem("privateChat", JSON.stringify(this.privateChat))
    },
    clickAllSounds(value) {
      this.allSounds = !this.allSounds
      localStorage.setItem("allSounds", JSON.stringify(this.allSounds))
    }
    setup() {
      const mobileMenuOpen = ref(false)
      const privateChatEnabled = ref(privateChat)
      let privateChatValue = localStorage.getItem("privateChat");
      let privateChat = (privateChatValue === 'true')
      const allSoundsEnabled = ref(allSounds)
      let allSoundsValue = localStorage.getItem("allSounds")
      let allSounds = (allSoundsValue === 'true')

      return {
        sidebarNavigation,
        userNavigation,
        mobileMenuOpen,
        tabs,
        userlists,
        team,
        activityItems,
        privateChatEnabled,
        allSoundsEnabled,
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Actually that isnt true. I have this working on "dark mode" where it toggles a div. I am not using JSON for that and it stores the data just fine in local storage. I accept that your answer might work (haven't personally tested) however that just adds some unnecessary complexity to a simple problem...

Comment: You could store the strings `"true"` or `"false"`, but that's what `JSON.stringify()` will do.

Comment: That is what I need to do - store in local storage true/false for allSounds and privateChat then call on them when needed

Comment: Using JSON.stringify is simpler than writing `localStorage.set("privateChat", this.privateChat ? "true" : "false")`